# Websphere port when I restarted saying already in use

Tags: sockets, websphere, websphere-8

Hi Can someone plese help me to solve the following issue.

I have started my websphere server and it is using the following ports

TCP_1 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9061.
TCP_2 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9081.
TCP Channel TCP_4 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9444.

When I stoped and started my server again I'm getting message saying that

**TCP Channel TCP_3 initialization failed.  The socket bind failed for host * and port 9043.  The port may already be in use.**

Can anyone advise me why it is not stopping automatically

Aprreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you verified that the java process is no longer running when you have shut down the server? When it is stopped you can also check which ports that are in use. How you do that is depending on the operating system you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem is well known and is usually caused by the fact that there are still TCP connections from the previous WAS process (i.e. before restarting it) using the port.

Eventually the port will be released and the new WAS process will be able to bind it.

One way to overcome this annoyance is to set the [**soReuseAddr**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rrun_chain_tcpcustom.html) property to **1** in the TCP transport channel.

Answer (score 0):

9043 is the Admin Console secure port.  Do you have a dmgr running on this server in addition to a stand alone app server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure though. Can you advise me how to check whether it is running?